# error java.lang.NullPointerException in android studio 2.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem while opening the project in *Android Studio 2.2.2*

The error appears:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.workspace.OCWorkspaceManager.getWorkspace(OCWorkspaceManager.java:12)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.clearAllSymbolDependentCaches(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:381)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.access$400(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:47)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$7.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:241)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$14$1.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:420)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1009)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity$14.run(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:416)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

image > https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKt6u.png

Comment: Do search for the problem, NullPointerException to see the most common similar question. Also post the exception stacktrace as code-formatted text, not as an image, post your code, and show where in your code the exception is being thrown.

Comment: go through this --> (same issue mentioned )
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205399

Comment: _Finally, I noticed that the exception window shows the NPE comes from the NDK support plugin. So I disabled and restarted AS to enable the plugin and the NPE is gone!_ .. Quoting from a post that @CharukaSilva posted.

Comment: Discussion on the same issue is found here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205399 rebuild fixed their issue

Comment: @KNeerajLal: good to know, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Kaushal28 No. The error is in the IDE, not the user code.